# How to dynamically bind multiple series to a stacked column chart

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, charts

I am using DevExpress charting but I think the binding should be the same throughout most charting tools. Here is some sample code using WPF charting tool instead. The code may not be 100% correct but I wanted to give a general idea of what I need. (My question is listed after)

```
<charting:Chart x:Name="MyChart"  Padding="10,10,10,10">
<charting:Chart.Series>
    <charting:StackedColumnSeries>
        <charting:SeriesDefinition Title="MyCollection1" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstCollection}" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" />
        <charting:SeriesDefinition Title="MyCollection2" ItemsSource="{Binding SecondCollection}" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" />
    </charting:StackedColumnSeries>
</charting:Chart.Series>
```

Binds to the following:

```
public IEnumerable FirstCollection
{
    get
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, long> kvp = new List<KeyValuePair<string, long>>();
        kvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, long>("2015", 200);
        kvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, long>("2016", 200);
        kvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, long>("2017", 200);
        return kvp;
    }
    set{
        NotifyPropertyChanged(FirstCollection);
    }

}
public IEnumerable SecondCollection
{
    get
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, long> kvp = new List<KeyValuePair<string, long>>();
        kvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, long>("2015", 200);
        kvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, long>("2016", 200);
        kvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, long>("2017", 200);
        return kvp;
    }
    set{
        NotifyPropertyChanged(SecondCollection);
    }

}
```

What I need is to create a list of these collections (FirstCollection to SomeNumberOfCollection) and be able to bind these multiple series to the stacked column chart without doing each one individually since the code should not know a set amount of series to bind to.

How do I bind this dynamic list of collections to the chart in XAML? I tried binding the list to the StackedColumnSeries rather than the SeriesDefinition but it does not contain any databinding properties (i.e. DataSource/ItemsSource)